# Customise the author URL in wordpress to display user information

Tags: php, wordpress, author

I am looking to use the author.php template to display information about each user.

I am running a loop to get users but when I click through I cant seem to grab any information relating to that user?

```
 <?php

 $members = get_users();

 foreach ( $members as $member ) { ?>

      <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($member->ID); ?>">View User</a>

 <?php } ?>
```

How can I retrieve the firstname etc in the author.php file? For some reason it wont pull through to display anything. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because your $members array is empty on return call to get_users()

You need to supply an argument for get_users() to be the matching filter criteria.

Comment: Thanks. Im still struggling to retrieve the user in my author.php file. Any ideas? It keeps returning info about the admin im logged in as, as opposed to the user im trying to pass. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass $args to `get_users` in order to return the results you're looking for.

See WordPress docs for [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

Just tested this code in author.php and it works, but realistically should work in anywhere you want it (not just author.php):

```
    $args = array(
        'blog_id'      => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
        'role'         => '',
        'role__in'     => array(),
        'role__not_in' => array(),
        'meta_key'     => '',
        'meta_value'   => '',
        'meta_compare' => '',
        'meta_query'   => array(),
        'date_query'   => array(),
        'include'      => array(),
        'exclude'      => array(),
        'orderby'      => 'login',
        'order'        => 'ASC',
        'offset'       => '',
        'search'       => '',
        'number'       => '',
        'count_total'  => false,
        'fields'       => 'all',
        'who'          => '',
     );
    $members = get_users( $args );

  foreach ( $members as $member ) { ?>

       <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($member->ID); ?>">View User</a>

  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Robert thanks for that. I need it so i add the above code to my template and then when you click view user, it goes to a child page and I can then make a template to show more detailed information about that user. So I have the above code added to my page template file and need to retrieve the user in author.php, which doesn't seem to work. Thank you.

Comment: So, if you're viewing yoursite.com/author/admin you want it to display info about that specific author, correct?